# How to add rows and cols as a list into a matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, multidimensional-array, collections

First I have init a 2D Array:

```
List<List<T>> matrix; // matrix is an 2D array;
public Table(Class<T> t) {;
    matrix = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
}
```

Then I have a addCow and addRow method:

```
public void addRow(int i) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for ( int j = 0; j < cols(); j++ )
    {
        list.add(null);
    }
    matrix.add(i, list);//add a list of null to the matrix
}

public void addCol(int j) {
    if (rows() == 0) return;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows(); i++){
      matrix.get(i).add(j, null);// HERE IS MY PROBLEMS
    }
}
```

The output is

[image: program output].

So my problem is, how to add a column as a list(or a full collections) into the matrix, like addRow method did, right now addCol was adding the elements one by one into the matrix and I got the error "Correctness failed: Number of cols in table is incorrect after adding new col."
I think the problem is I add column as elements one by one not as a set.

Comment: what is the expected output of your program? Why is array`[][]` not a useful data structure for you?

Comment: what is the actual problem ? is the problem just `right now addCol was adding the elements one by one into the matrix` and if it is, why ? is it not working ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Collection, then use `addAll()`